# Export file - Active profile file is empty

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Eclipse 2023

I want to use one java editor format for all members of team.
Some people work on Eclipse and some people work on IntelIJ IDEA.
I need only ONE file to share.
So I try this:

```
Windows->Preference->Java->Code style->Formatter->Export All
```

[image]

Here result of exported xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<profiles version="23"/>
```

Why file is empty?

Comment: Why would you need to export an already built-in profile?

Comment: @nitind I want to use same formatter for all members  of teams

Comment: I can reproduce it in Eclipse 2023-09 (please make sure it has been reported [here](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui/issues), best with a pull request). Duplicating the built-in profile via the _New..._ button and then exporting works for me as a workaround. Anyhow, the recommended way to share the formatter settings in your projects is as follows: in _Project > Properties: Java Code Style > Formatter_, check the checkbox _Enable project specific settings_.

Comment: @howlger Project > Properties: Java Code Style > Formatter, check the checkbox Enable project specific settings  - Same result. Export file is empty.

Comment: With project specific formatter settings you do not need to export the formatter profile. Just make sure that the project's `.settings` folder will be shared.

Comment: @howlger .settings not a solution. Because I want to share ONE file between all members of teams. Some work on Eclipse and some work on IntelIJ Idea.

Comment: You can do it via the workaround as described in my first comment. But I would recommend to share the `.settings` folder, which will not cause problems when using different IDEs. A project should be self-contained and global settings are hard to change. So better have something for synchronizing the settings of all projects that has not yet been archived.